# A non-DP ViewModel needs a property set when something else changes

Tags: xaml, mvvm

I have a UserControl which displays data associated with the active Person in the system. This UC has a DependencyProperty 'Person' which is set by whomever 'owns' the instance of the UC.

To display the data associated with Person in the UC I have a ViewModel. The ViewModel needs to know which person is currently set in the UC's Person.

Initially I tried this:

```
...snip...
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ...snip...

        <vms:TheViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" Person={Binding somebinding to the UC's Person}/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
...snip...
```

This produced an error because TheViewModel is not a DependencyObject. I'd rather not make it a dependency object since I don't want those pesky "do stuff in the UI thread only" issues.

**What is a clean way to bind a DP from a UC into a non-DP property of a VM instantiated in XAML?**

I currently have one, possibly hacky, maybe unclean solution. I haven't run it just yet but i'm confident it should work. This follows:

In TheViewModel I create 2 attached properties. Person and VM. In the UC I create a dud Separator which is Collapsed and to which the Person-AP and VM-AP are set. In the change event of the Person-AP, I get the VM from the VM-AP and then set it's Patient non-dp-p accordingly.

```
...snip...
<DockPanel>
    <!--Hacky Separator used only as a binding object to help the VM-->
    <Separator DockPanel.Dock="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"
            vms:TheViewModel.Person="{Binding ElementName=uiControlMe, Path=Person}"
            vms:TheViewModel.VM="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" />
...snip...
```

**Is there a better way?**

Thank you.

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong with your understanding of DP and ViewModels. You **never** use DP with ViewModel, DP is there for the usercontrols to expose a binding for a ViewModel to bind to. DPs only work with DependencyObjects (which user controls are), because the value of a DP is stored on the `DependencyObject` itself

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know that turning a ViewModel into a DO is a bad idea. I know that I can't put a DP into a non-DO. My question relates to being able to set a value in my ViewModel normal property from a DP in a user control.

Comment: Let me guess--you built a user control to represent a person, then you created a view model for that user control which controls the encapsulated logic within it?  Now, if that's the case, think about the reasons *why* I might have known.

Comment: I created a person data-only class. I created a view model to contain logic to create-new/save-to-db/revert/load-from-db/maintain-a-list-of-persons/keep-track-of-an-active-person. I then created a few views for Persons, one which lets me view the active Person in the 'app-wide' view model instance of Person, and another which displays assoc data to a Person (not necessarily the active Person). This particular "TheViewModel" is an instance of a non-Person view model that requires the knowledge of a single Person to display data for the assoc-data-to-a-Person view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Dependency property changes, get the View Model resource and set the property on the View Model.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Person", typeof(PersonObject),
    typeof(MyUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
      new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPersonChanged) )
    );

private static void OnPersonChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  var vm = (TheViewModel)this.Resources["ViewModel"];
  Person p = (PersonObject) d;
  vm.Person = p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, your approach is a valid one. I hadn't thought to make it through the code-behind. I was trying to keep the binding in the xaml. Maybe keeping it in the xaml is a 'bastardization'.

Comment: Actually, i'm going to undo my xaml-hack and just you do your suggestion. Your approach is not hacky, whereas mine is - which makes mine less maintainable and bad. Thank you.

Comment: My goal in this case was maintainability.